# (Java) Use instance of a class implenting an interface as parameter

Tags: java

I want to calculate a person's BMI by passing an instance of that person as parameter in class BMI static method calculate() as follows:

**Main.java**

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        John john = new John(182, 68);
        BMI.calculate(john); // NaN???
    }
}
```

**Physique.java**

```java
public interface Physique {
    int height = 0;
    int weight = 0;
}
```

**John.java** (implements Physique interface)

```java
public class John implements Physique {
    int height;
    int weight;
    int age;

    public John(int height, int weight, int age) {
        this.weight = weight;
        this.height = height;
    }

}
```

**BMI.java**

```java
public class BMI {

    public static void calculate(Physique physique) { // problem?
        System.out.println(physique.height / Math.pow(physique.weight, 2));
    }
}
```

I figure the problem should be my misuse of interface as type in paramater in BMI class.
It works if I use `calculate(John john)`, but if I have another person, that won't work. How could I correctly implement this?

Comment: Your problem is your interface's properties `int width` and `int height`, this seem to be getting "defaulted" over `John`s implementation -  in fact, they don't even make up part of the interface's over all required - try removing `height` and `width` from `John`, the compiler won't compiler about non-compliance with the interface.  Instead, define two methods, `getWidth` and `getHeight` both which return `int`

Comment: You might also want to read [Attributes / member variables in interfaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7311274/attributes-member-variables-in-interfaces)

Comment: @MadProgrammer thank you very much, I just solved the problem thanks to your suggestion. It seems I need encapsulation over ```height``` and ```weight```