# Passing Object Through Method in Java

Tags: java, object, methods, abstraction

I am trying to get a second object to pass through my method so that I can add values from each object. I am trying to access the numerator attribute and denominator attribute from the "secondRational" object.

```
@Override
public RationalInterface add(RationalInterface secondRational) {
    // How do I access the secondRational values within the child class Rational?
    int numerator = this.num * secondRational.den + this.den * secondRational.num;
    int denominator = this.den * secondRational.den;
    this.num = numerator;
    this.den = denominator;
    return this;
} // end add
```

The error that I receive is that the den symbol for secondRational is not resolved.

[image]

Comment: What us the question? Are you having any errors?

Comment: You probably assume that someone will look at the code of the method that you posted and tell you how to fix it. I very much doubt that will happen. I suggest that you read [ask] and pay particular attention to the part about how to write a [mcve]. By the way, an interface cannot have [attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7311274/attributes-member-variables-in-interfaces).

Comment: It's very simple. `this.den` does not exist.

Comment: @TimRoberts What difference would that make? A: none.

Comment: What's the definition of `RationalInterface`? As an interface, it can only have methods and static attributes. `den` is not a method (that would be `den()` ) and a static would not make sense.

Answer (score -1):

To access the numerator and denominator attributes from the secondRational object, you need to use the dot notation. For example, to access the numerator attribute, you would use the following code:

int numerator = secondRational.numerator;
To access the denominator attribute, you would use the following code:

int denominator = secondRational.denominator;
You can then use these variables in your code to perform the addition operation.

Here is an updated version of your code that uses the dot notation to access the secondRational values:

```
@Override
public RationalInterface add(RationalInterface secondRational) {

    // Access the numerator and denominator values from the secondRational object
    int numerator = this.num * secondRational.denominator + this.den * secondRational.numerator;
    int denominator = this.den * secondRational.denominator;

    // Update the numerator and denominator values for the current object
    this.num = numerator;
    this.den = denominator;

    // Return the current object
    return this;
} // end add
```

Comment: Why do you think this will work?  `this` and `secondRational` are of the same type.  If `den` works for one, then it would work for the other.  They were already using dot notation, which suggests to me that this answer may not have been human-generated.